# Why can't I change my profile picture for chat?

Tags: support

I'm unable to make any changes in my chat profile.  My site profile is not being replicated to chat.  Currently, chat still uses my old name and profile picture.  Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sometimes it takes up to an hour for changes (especially rep) to sync with the chat account. Was your update within that window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: [Caching.](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Contestant: "What should I blame when something doesn't match across the site?"

Your chat profile has updated from the original:

[image: Original Chat profile]

To match your new Stack Overflow profile:

[image: New Chat profile]

It can be seen here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/128709/

I found your chat profile by following the instructions from the [February Mod Newsletter](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/):

> You can now reach a user’s chat profile by heading to `https://chat.stackexchange.com/accounts/[networkid]`, where `[networkid]`corresponds to the user’s Stack Exchange Network ID. You can determine that value from a user when visiting their profile page on any site by clicking “network profile” in the top right (or if your browser supports it, hovering over the link to view the URL), and copying the number from the resulting address. If the user does not actually have a chat profile linked to their account, you will instead be directed to a 404 page when you input that network ID.
>
> This route is available for anyone to use, it is not moderator-only. It is, however, most likely to be of use to moderators when trying to determine a user’s chat identity for the purposes of superpings. We’re considering how to integrate this directly into the profiles, rather than requiring a manually input URL.